# Map overlays in android

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I would like to ask about how can I add different overlays to my android application?
as I already have one overlay class that extends Overlay and it draws  polylines according to some points in a KML file.
and now I would like to create another overlay that adds a pin in the user's location using GPS, so I don't know how this could be done.

please anyone knows how to help me ?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a pin to the user's location use MyLocationOverlay it's in the google maps API see this [link](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=148)

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple overlays on top of one map.

Just create the second layer as an `ItemizedOverlay`, and add it to the map:

    `myMapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);`

To learn how to add markers to an `ItemizedOverlay`, see http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-itemizedoverlay-to-add-marker-on.html.

Answer (score 0):

[Android GoogleMaps API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/overview-tree) may also help.